# reRender a specific column of rich:dataTable

Tags: jsf, richfaces

Is it possible to reRender only 1 specific column of rich:dataTable?

I tried giving the column an id and reRender="columnId" but that just crashed the page.

If so, how?

```
<f:facet name="header">
    <rich:columnGroup>
        <rich:column>
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#NotepadManagementGenControl.returnAllNotepads}" >
                 <a4j:support event="onclick" action="#{NotepadManagementGenControl.returnNotepadToggleAll}" reRender="myColumn"/>
            </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
            <h:outputText value="#{l.return1}"></h:outputText>
        </rich:column>
    </rich:columnGroup>
</f:facet>
<rich:column id="myColumn">
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{dataItem.returnNotepad}" />
</rich:column>
```

Comment: Yes It is possible !! You have not provided any specific detail and code snippet so can't guess the reason!! But if the rerendering action is executed from within the column don't rerender your column, rerender the datatable.

Comment: richfaces 3.3 or 4? jsf 1.2 or 2.0?

Comment: RF4 doesn't have `<a4j:support>` anymore, so I'll bet RF 3.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this with reRendering not the column but the booleanCheckBox itself (and thus reRendering al checkboxes in column).